# how to create and pass more or less json payload in karate at runtime

Tags: karate

Sometimes I have to pass following payload

```
{
   "code": "hhhh",
   "name": "NDS coupon Testing",
   "description": "NDS couopn testing via postman",
   "status": "ACTIVE",
   "comments": null,
   "rules": {
               "AND":[{
                                       "rule":{
                                       "operator" : "EQ",
                                       "status" : "ACTIVE",
                                       "attribute_name" : "HOTEL_ID",
                                       "attribute_value" : "12744",
                                       "attribute_value_type" : "INTEGER"
                                       }
                               }]        
}
}
```

And sometimes following payload

```
{
   "code": "hhhh",
   "name": "NDS coupon Testing",
   "description": "NDS couopn testing via postman",
   "status": "ACTIVE",
   "comments": null,
   "rules": {
               "AND":[{
                                       "rule":{
                                       "operator" : "EQ",
                                       "status" : "ACTIVE",
                                       "attribute_name" : "HOTEL_ID",
                                       "attribute_value" : "12744",
                                       "attribute_value_type" : "INTEGER"
                                       }
                               }
{

              "AND" : [{"rule" : {

                       "status" : "ACTIVE",
                       "operator" : "EQUALS_LT"
                       "attribute_name" : "checkout",
                       "attribute_value" : "2018-12-31T00:00:00-05:30",
                       "attribute_value_type" : "DATE_TIME"
                      }

                 },]        
}
}
```

and my framework structure is 
**payload.json** which has default payload. Now in my feature file I load payload.json **set** values which I want to update , but how to add / remove some part of json at runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. For further reading I suggest the following sections:

- [Embedded Expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions)
- [Remove if Null](https://github.com/intuit/karate#remove-if-null)
- [Conditional Logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic)
- [Set and Remove](https://github.com/intuit/karate#remove)

And it would have been really nice if you had taken the time to ensure your JSON is well-formed. Anyway.

```
* def json =
"""
{
  "code": "hhhh",
  "name": "NDS coupon Testing",
  "description": "NDS couopn testing via postman",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "comments": null,
  "rules": {
    "AND": [
      {
        "rule": {
          "operator": "EQ",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "attribute_name": "HOTEL_ID",
          "attribute_value": "12744",
          "attribute_value_type": "INTEGER"
        }
      },
      {
        "rule": {
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "operator": "EQUALS_LT",
          "attribute_name": "checkout",
          "attribute_value": "2018-12-31T00:00:00-05:30",
          "attribute_value_type": "DATE_TIME"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
"""
* eval if (true) karate.remove('json', '$.rules.AND[1]')
* print json
```

Comment: This works fine because I have 2 rules , What if I have more rules block to be added

Comment: @SourabhChapali read the links I posted. there are many options. you can always use a JS function with a `switch case` or multiple `if - then` statements

Comment: Thank you very much